# How to split the string by '/' and reform it by the split substrings in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to split the words based on the character '/' and reform the words in this way:

This dataframe contains some kids and their presents for Easter. Some kids have two presents, while some have only one.

```
data = {'Presents':['Pink Doll / Ball', 'Bear/ Ball', 'Barbie', 'Blue Sunglasses/Airplane', 'Orange Kitchen/Car', 'Bear/Doll', 'Purple Game'],
        'Kids':  ['Chris', 'Jane', 'Betty', 'Harry', 'Claire', 'Sofia', 'Alex']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Presents', 'Kids'])

print (df)
```

This dataframe looks like this:

```
                   Presents    Kids
0          Pink Doll / Ball   Chris
1                Bear/ Ball    Jane
2                    Barbie   Betty
3  Blue Sunglasses/Airplane   Harry
4        Orange Kitchen/Car  Claire
5                 Bear/Doll   Sofia
6               Purple Game    Alex
```

I try to delimit their presents and also to reform them in this way, keeping their associated colors:

`'Pink Doll/Ball'` will be split into two parts: `'Pink Doll'`, `'Pink Ball'`. In addition to this, the *same kid* should be associated to their presents.

The colours and the presents can be anything, we just know that the **structure** is: **Colour Present1/Present2**, or **Colour Present** or just **Present**. So finally, it should be:

- for Colour Present/Present --> Colour Present1 and Colour Present2
- for Colour Present ---> Colour Present
- for Present ---> Present

So the final dataframe should look like this:

```
           Presents    Kids
0         Pink Doll   Chris
1         Pink Ball   Chris
2              Bear    Jane
3              Ball    Jane
4            Barbie   Betty
5   Blue Sunglasses   Harry
6     Blue Airplane   Harry
7    Orange Kitchen  Claire
8        Orange Car  Claire
9              Bear   Sofia
10             Doll   Sofia
11      Purple Game    Alex
```

My first approach was to transform the columns into lists and work with lists. Like this:

```
def count_total_words(string):
    total = 1
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if (string[i] == ' '):
            total = total + 1
    return total

coloured_presents_to_remove_list = []
index_with_slash_list = []
first_present = ''
second_present= ''
index_with_slash = -1
refactored_second_present = ''
for coloured_present in coloured_presents_list:
    if (coloured_present.find('/') >= 0):
        index_with_slash = coloured_presents_list.index(coloured_present)
        index_with_slash_list.append(index_with_slash)
        first_present, second_present = coloured_present.split('/')
        coloured_presents_to_remove_list.append(coloured_present)
        if count_total_words(first_present) == 2:
            refactored_second_present = first_present.split(' ', 1)[0] + ' ' + second_present
            second_present = refactored_second_present
        coloured_presents_list.append(first_present)
        coloured_presents_list.append(second_present)
        kids_list.insert(coloured_presents_list.index(first_present), kids_list[index_with_slash])
        kids_list.insert(coloured_presents_list.index(second_present), kids_list[index_with_slash])
        
for present in coloured_presents_to_remove_list:
    coloured_presents_list.remove(present)

for index in index_with_slash_list:
    kids_list.pop(index)
```

However, I have realized that in some point, I might lose some index by mistake so I tried working with pandas into dataframe.

```
mask = df['Presents'].str.contains('/', na=False, regex=False)
df['First Present'], df['Second Present'] = df.loc[mask, 'Presents'].split('/')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
s = df['Presents'].str.split('/')
a , b = s.str[0].str.strip() , s.str[-1].str.strip()
c = a.str.count(' ').gt(0) & s.str.len().ge(2)
arr = np.where(c,b.radd(a.str.split().str[0].str.strip()+' '),b)
out = (pd.concat((a,pd.Series(arr,index=s.index,name=s.name)))
       .sort_index().to_frame().join(df[['Kids']]))
pd.DataFrame.drop_duplicates(out)
```

The results are these by using the above code:

```
         Presents    Kids
0        Pink Doll   Chris
0        Pink Ball   Chris
1             Bear    Jane
1             Ball    Jane
2           Barbie   Betty
2           Barbie   Betty
3  Blue Sunglasses   Harry
3    Blue Airplane   Harry
4   Orange Kitchen  Claire
4       Orange Car  Claire
5             Bear   Sofia
5             Doll   Sofia
6      Purple Game    Alex
6      Purple Game    Alex
```

Happy Coding!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `str.split` using a `regex` with `expand=True` to get your first and second present. Note that this will handle the three cases `'present1/present2'`, `'coulour present'` and `'present'`. In the latter two cases the newly created column `'present2'` will be `None`.

To handle the case `'colour present1/present2'` you can use `str.extract` with a regular expression containing permissible colours (see `colours_regex` below). This is to distinguish colour from presents consisting of two words (e.g `'Barby Doll'`).

The final step is then to use `melt` with `'Kids'` as an identifier

```
df[['present1', 'present2']] = df.Presents.str.split('\s*/\s*', expand=True)
colours_regex = '(Blue|Purple|Pink|Orange)'  # maybe not ideal if there are vast amounts of colours as this needs updating for every colour
df['colour'] = df.present1.str.extract(colours_regex)
df.loc[df.colour.notnull()&df.present2.notnull(), 'present2'] = df.loc[df.colour.notnull()&df.present2.notnull(), ['colour', 'present2']].agg(' '.join, axis=1)
result = df.melt(id_vars='Kids', value_vars=['present1', 'present2'], value_name='Present')
result = result.loc[result.Present.notnull(), ['Present', 'Kids']]
```

Comment: i think your missing the logic to add color to presents that don't have them

Comment: It doesn't work, it gives me the error TypeError: split() got multiple values for argument 'pat', and I tried to repair it but I am not sure exactly how :(

Comment: now gives: KeyError: "Passing list-likes to .loc or [] with any missing labels is no longer supported. The following labels were missing: Index(['kids'], dtype='object'). See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#deprecate-loc-reindex-listlike"

Comment: Thank you, I know understand what you meant by that case, it works, but with that exception.

Comment: @ElisaL. I've made an update to handle the colours.